# How to fetch multiple records from a fetch statement in SQLRPGLE?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

Recently in an interview I was asked how to fetch multiple record using a single fetch statement in SQLRPGLE. I would like to know is it possible to get multiple record using a single fetch statement, if yes then can some one elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [SQL Reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=statements-fetch) and the [Embedded SQL Programming manual](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=cssiira-using-host-structure-arrays-in-ile-rpg-applications-that-use-sql)

Basic form is

```
FETCH FROM <cursor_name> FOR <nbr_rows> INTO :array_name
```

From the Embedded SQL Programming manual, note that `FROM` is optional unless you're  specifing a new position for the cursor via the `NEXT, PRIOR, FIRST, LAST, BEFORE, AFTER, CURRENT, and RELATIVE` keywords.

```
DCL-DS fststruct DIM(10) QUALIFIED;
  sub1 INT(5);
  sub2 INT(10);
  sub3 INT(20);
  sub4 INT(10);
END-DS;

EXEC SQL FETCH C1 FOR 10 ROWS INTO :fststruct;
```